# Nodeclipse on Eclipse Mars

Tags: node.js, eclipse-plugin, enide

I  have installed Enide2015 plugin  [image: Enide2015]

for Eclipse Mars[image: Eclipse4.5.1]
***Here is the issue***:
When I create a Node.js project Eclipse does not respond at all
[image: Node.JS project]

Since Node.exe is in different folder than the  work space where I am creating Node.JS project, I tried to specify the path , in 2 ways:
1) in Eclipse IDE :Window->preference->NodeEclipse(  eclipse Hanging)
2)User variable PATH- Successful
But even with 2) , issue still persist.

Additional info:
a)  I tried to specify  where to look for Node.exe  in Window->Preference->NodeEclipse , **but eclipse hangs and I am not able to enter any value**
[image: Preferences]

b) I have set the user variable PATH to point to Node.exe directory
[image: PATH user variable]

c)Here is the Node directory[image: Node directory]

d)Here are the node components installed[image: Node components]

e) Here are the Tern components installed[image: Tern components]

Has anyone run into this issue? Am I missing any requirements? I searched eclipse bug list , did not see anything promising. Looked at the Nodeeclipse dependencies- seems I am Ok there as well.

JPS + JSTACK UI freeze

- java.io.BufferedReader.readLine() @bci=2 (Compiled frame)
- org.nodeclipse.ui.util.ProcessUtils.exec(java.util.List,
  java.io.File) @bci=139, line=190 (Interpreted frame)
- org.nodeclipse.ui.util.ProcessUtils.getCurrentVersionOf(java.lang.String)
  @bci=40, line=74

Line 183-200[ProcessUtils.exec](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/util/ProcessUtils.java#L183-L200) maybe something to investigate. My Java version is 1.8.0_60

Based on what I heard from Eclipse, it is a Nodeclipse issue [id=488326](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488326)